# I send variables to export.php through Ajax, but it is not received in export page

Tags: ajax

I send variables to export.php through Ajax, but it is not received in export page. it shows

> Undefined index: name in D:\xampp\htdocs\Vergands - Admin1\export.php on line 2

customer.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".export_button").click(function(){
           var tableName = $("#tableName").val();

           $.ajax({
                method:"post",
                url:"export.php",
                data:{name:tableName}

               });
        });
    });
</script>
```

export.php  /*its working fine when i run export.php alone and excel file getting downloaded( using 
this function export('customer_profile'); 
customer_profile is table name 
 */

```
  <?php

    $tableName_final = $_POST["name"];

     function export($tableName_final){


            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "admin_vergands";
            //mysql and db connection

            $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            if ($con->connect_error) {  //error check
                die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
            }
            else
            {
            echo "connection failed";
            }



            $DB_TBLName = $tableName; 
            $filename = "excelfilename";  //your_file_name
            $file_ending = "xls";   //file_extention

            header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");  
            header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
            header("Expires: 0");

            $sep = "\t";

            $sql="SELECT * FROM $DB_TBLName"; 
            $resultt = $con->query($sql);
            while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($resultt)) { //fetch table field name
                echo $property->name."\t";
            }

            print("\n");    

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultt))  //fetch_table_data
            {
                $schema_insert = "";
                for($j=0; $j< mysqli_num_fields($resultt);$j++)
                {
                    if(!isset($row[$j]))
                        $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
                    elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                        $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
                    else
                        $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
                }
                $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
                $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
                $schema_insert .= "\t";
                print(trim($schema_insert));
                print "\n";
            }
        }
    export($tableName_final);

    ?>
```

Comment: have you tried `var_dump($_POST['data])`;

Comment: "Call to undefined function vardump()" i got this error

Comment: its `var_dump` not `vardump`

Comment: sorry i forgot var_dump syntax, i am getting null error

Comment: check your browser's network tab when the ajax request is made - does the "name" variable get sent in the request body? If not, then put an alert to check that `tableName` actually has a value before you send it. Simple debugging steps which you should be doing already to trace your problem back to the source.

Comment: tableName value is there , i confirmed with alert ,before i used

Comment: i already check with alert function tableName do exist, before i used   include "export.php" when i removed is doesn't show any error ,but there no solution yet why i am not getting value in export.php

Comment: in network (xhr)  the status is 200 (ok) that means data is send ,then why is not echo'ed

Comment: Are you certain it's the ajax which is making the request? Is "export-button" also a form submit button? Could it be doing a normal postback as well? Also try just `var_dump($_POST);` in case the $_POST looks different somehow. Is there anything at all in there?

Comment: <input type="hidden"  value="customer_profile" id="tableName">      <button  type="button" class="export_button"  >                                                  i want to know variables pass through ajax can able to echo (or) its only for responding  back to requested page                                                                                               because i am trying to get ajax value and store it into string and passing as a parameter  for export function(the variable i am trying to pass trough parameter is table name)

Comment: i am very eager to get this solution

Comment: "i want to know variables pass through ajax can able to echo (or) its only for responding back to requested page". Those two things are the same. The echo goes back to the requested page within the response. In your ajax code above you actually are ignoring that response. Are you trying to save the variable for later when a separate request is made? If so then you need to persist it somehow. HTTP requests are stateless. The PHP script is executed in isolation every time you request it. Variable values do not persist between requests unless you save them somewhere, e.g. session or database.

Comment: Your code seems OK. please post more code and a print-screen from with network request header.

Comment: i added my full code